# Getting 404 when i try to call endpoint with multiple query parameter

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I do it like this
`curl http://localhost:9000/vehicle?time=10:10:10&x=2&y=2`
and the routes in Router are defined like

```
override def routes: Routes = {
    case GET(p"/" ? q"time=$time" & q"x=${int(x)}" & q"y=${int(y)}") =>
      controller.getVehicle(time, x, y)

    case GET(p"/"? q"stop_id=${stopId}") =>
      controller.getVehicle(stopId)

    case GET(p"/delay/"?q"line_id=${lineId}") =>
      controller.getDelay(lineId)
  }
```

routes file looks like

```
GET     /vehicle    transport.TransportController.getVehicle(time: String, x: Int, y: Int)
->         /v1/posts                                v1.post.PostRouter
->         /vehicle                                 transport.TransportRouter
->         /vehicle/delay                             transport.TransportRouter
```

with dynamic routing SIRD
It gives me
[debug] a.ErrorHandler - onClientError: statusCode = 404, uri = /vehicle?time=10:10:10, message =

and with static

```
GET /vehicle transport.TransportController.getVehicle(time: String, x: Int, y: Int)
```

I get
[debug] a.ErrorHandler - onClientError: statusCode = 400, uri = /vehicle?time=10:10:10, message = Missing parameter: x

Where's the error? Why it isn't picking the remaining parameters?

Comment: Well, there's no `package controllers` line above the declaration of `TransportController`, so what do you expect?
If you want useful answers, provide a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Honestly, if people did that, 80% of all questions would simply disappear.

Comment: They are in a package, I just didn't post it here. The error was in the route file, I fixed it. 
But regardless, it still gives me the other error. 
When i do curl. only takes time and not x y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your code problem, it's your curl command problem. Ampersand is treated differently, not as a query parameter in your case. Try to add quotation marks around your url:

```
curl "http://localhost:9000/vehicle?time=10:10:10&x=2&y=2"
```